# d3.js - maintain interaction with use of canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, d3.js

As far as I read about this topic d3.js uses for the main part SVG and not HTML5's Canvas. The advantages and disadvantages of SVG and Canvas are clear and already discussed. Now I found out that it is possible to use Canvas instead or in combination with SVG in d3.js. The main reason should be to get a better performance for large datasets (like cubism.js does for realtime data visualization). My question is: When I do use Canvas over SVG to get a better performance, do I have still the possibilities of interaction? I know that Canvas itself allows manipulation, but it is much harder to implement than it is for SVG. So can I maintain the interaction of SVGs when I use the d3.js Canvas approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, D3 doesn't require any specific rendering technology as such. It is mostly (except for some specialised helpers) agnostic of whether you use HTML, SVG, Canvas or something completely different for rendering.

One of the main differences between SVG and Canvas, as you've pointed out, is that SVG has the interaction "built in", i.e. it provides facilities for event listeners and such. Canvas has none of this.

You can however get the same kind of interactivity as in SVG in Canvas. The trick is to use Javascript to monitor what the user does in relation to the various elements. For an introduction to this, see e.g. [here](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful).

Note that, depending on what kind of interaction you want exactly, there may be significant implementation effort to achieve the same as SVG already provides. Also note that this incurs a performance penalty which may negate some of the benefits of Canvas over SVG.